# jQuery datetimepicker not work on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have a dynamic time field in which I used [`jQuery Datetime picker`](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker).

For dynamic initialization I used this code:

```
 $("body").on("focus",".time-input",function(){
        $(this).datetimepicker();
 });
```

But it works when I focus for second time.

A working demo would be great, if possible.

Comment: try to change `$("body")` to `$(document)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you only instantiate the date picker on the element the first time it gets focussed, and then every time after, which isn't a good idea. Instead you only need to instantiate it on the element on load:

```
$(function() {
    $('.time-input').datetimepicker();
});
```

If the `.time-input` element is dynamically appended to the DOM (as I am assuming given the delegated event handler) then you need to call the `datepicker()` method on it at the point it's added to the DOM. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mypage.php',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.prop) {
            var $input = $('<input class="time-input" />').appendTo('#myForm');
            $input.datepicker();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but need is to create new elements dynamically with this class.

Comment: i have tried this but this only work for static elements and not for dynamic elements

Comment: You saw my update regarding dynamically added elements, right?

Comment: this is also not possible i cann't access the dynamically created element its inbuilt

Comment: If you are dynamically creating element the initialize datetimepicker only after element is created in DOM.

Comment: and what if its created by some other plug-in and i can't change the plugin code

Comment: If the plugin is any good it should raise an event when it completes it's task, or allows you to provide a callback, so that you can work with the amended DOM in there.

Comment: If it's a custom plugin, can you not add it

Comment: Use `setInterval` and check for new elements every 10ms and initialise if not already initialised....  seriously, get your "custom plugin" fixed or fork it and add the code needed.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the focusin event is used by the plugin to show the datepicker, the better solution is to initialize the plugin soon after the input elements are created, but if you can't do that, you can look at some workaround like

```js
$("body").on("focus", ".time-input", function() {
  if (!$(this).data('xdsoft_datetimepicker')) {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
      onGenerate: function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('initial')) {
          $(this).addClass('initial').triggerHandler('open.xdsoft');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#ct').append('<input class="time-input" />');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.4.5/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.4.5/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div id="ct">
  <input class="time-input" />
</div>
<button>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize datatimepicker on DOM element on document ready

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("focus",".time-input",function(){
       $(this).datetimepicker();
    });
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This is exactly the same as what the OP has now?

Answer (score 0):

Try "$(document.body)" instead "$(body)".

```
$(document.body).on('focus', '.time-input', function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set datepicker after your dom is created.Here your code is not working because jquery `datetimepicker` not open the tab when initialized. and second time you focus its work because its already initialized.

like this:

```
//here your dom should be updated you can console the length 
//console.log($('.time-input').length)
$('.time-input').each(function(){
  $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i dont know where to put this..as i don't know from where its created

Comment: you can check when event is triggered like after click or focus etc